How to implement a Web Terminal in fabric8-k8s-client (v6.9.2) + Spring Boot (v2.5.15) with support for key capture, copy-paste, etc.?
I am working with Spring Boot v2.5.15 and fabric8 Kubernetes client v6.9.2, and I want to implement a web terminal that can capture keystrokes, support copy-paste, and provide interactive terminal capabilities.
In Golang, SPDYExecutor and a stream handler are commonly used for this kind of functionality(ref:https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/modules/api/pkg/handler/terminal.go), but I haven’t found a similar approach in the fabric8 client. Is there a recommended way to build such a web terminal using Java and fabric8? Or perhaps other Java libraries that could help implement this functionality?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
